# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ive looked at duplicate errors like this but i havent found a solution

here is my method im implementing in the business logic

```
  public  void UpdateBooking(BookingView model)
    {
        using (var booking = new BookingRepository())
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser();
            Booking book = booking.GetById(model.BookingId);

            if (book != null)
            {

                book.BookingId = model.BookingId;
                book.BookingDate = model.BookingDate;
                book.BookingTime = model.BookingTime;
                book.Location = model.Location;
                //book.Status = DefaultStatus();
                //book.TreatmentName = book.TreatmentName;
                //book.AddInfo = model.AddInfo;

                booking.Update(book);
            }
        }
    }
```

but my error is on my booking controller method

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult postponeBooking([Bind(Include = "location,BookingDate,BookingTime")]BookingView model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            BookingBusiness.UpdateBooking(model);

        }
        return RedirectToAction("BookingDetails", TempData["alertMessage"] = "<script> alert('Booking details saved!!');</script>");
    }
```

exactly on this line

```
            BookingBusiness.UpdateBooking(model);
```

im completely clueless i tried adding static to my methods but still no luck.maybe im not understanding the error properly i need abit of guidance
thank you

Comment: If BookingBusiness is not a static class, you need an instance of it (i.e. do a `new BookingBusiness()` somewhere) and use that instance for the `UpdateBooking` method. You cannot call classes magically like that, unless they're static.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault ... looks like an answer :)

Comment: @JohnieKarr Looks like a duplicate, I'll flag it instead.

Comment: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property` the error is pretty explicit and means exactly what it says. `UpdateBooking` is an *instance* method and so you need an *instance* of `BookingBusiness` to call it. Now since your method doesn't appear to actually touch any members of the `BookingBusiness` class at all, you could just mark it static. If you whole class is like that, then probably the class should be static. Also note, if you make the a method static, it won't be able to call other instance methods either unless you give it an instance to work with.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: The class doesn't *have* to be static. You could just make that method static since it doesn't seem to be accessing any variables outside it's own scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505181/error-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-prop)

Answer (score 0):

To use your `UpdateBooking` method, either your `BookingBusiness` class or `UpdateBooking` method must be static (you won't refer to individual instance objects) OR you must instantiate an object of type `BookingBusiness` like so (obviously depending on how you intend on implementing these):

```
BookingBusiness yourObject = new BookingBusiness(/*constructor args*/);
```

Then you can call your method via `yourObject.UpdateBooking(model);`

Comment: thank you for pointing that out.i actually had instantiated an object of type bookingbusiness but i then forgot to use it to call my updatebooking method and used my bookingbusiness clss directly which is wrong.the help is appreciated

Comment: @minenhle, glad I could help. It's always funny when our issues are caused by such small mistakes :)

Comment: @DangerZone - It's not always funny!  Sometimes it's downright maddening!  :P

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, very true! At least this one gave an error. Can't tell you how many programs I've wasted hours on because I did something stupid like `myClass.ToString();` and expecting console output or `someString.Replace("X","O");` and expecting a different string from `someString` much later!