# Error CS0120: An object referenceis required for the non-static field, method or property 'MainMenu.timer1'. How can I fix it?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a basic C# game but code is not compiling, with the following error

> CS0120: An object referenceis required for the non-static field,
> method or property 'MainMenu.timer1'

This is the code:

```
try
{
    Ping myPing = new Ping();
    String host = "www.google.com";
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
    int timeout = 4000;
    PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
    PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("You aren't connected a internet or connection is to slow. Please check your connection.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    MainMenu.timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Here's the timer1's code:

```
public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (toolStripProgressBar1.Value <= 100)
    { 
        toolStripProgressBar1.Value += 1;
        string 123;
        123 = label3.Text;
        int 1, 2, answ;
        sayi1 = Convert.ToInt32(toolStripStatusLabel1.Text);
        sayi2 = Convert.ToInt32(123);
        answ = 1 + 2;
        string ans;
        ans = answ.ToString();
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = ans;
        external = ans;
        this.Text = "Game (%" + ans + ") - Wait";      
    }
    
    if (toolStripProgressBar1.Value >= 100)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"bin/MOOperator.exe");
        timer1.Stop();
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

I'm beginner at C# and I don't know much, thanks in advance for solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505181/error-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-prop)

Comment: Which line has the error?  Is the method containing that line `static` or not?  Please include relevant information in the question.

Comment: MainMenu.timer1.Enabled = false; on MainMenu.timer1

Comment: @Tim no it isn't worked on my code

Comment: @CanÖzkan - The reason for the error is the same, and the error is quite clear.  While the lined question may not be the same code as your code, the solution will be the same.

Comment: Where is `MainMenu` defined?

Comment: @Tim but i'm tried public static void and application thrown 21 more errors.

Comment: The function doesn't need to be static.  Either MainMenu or timer1 needs to be.  Can't tell which as you don't have the source for either in the OP.

Comment: maybe i found other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MainMenu.timer1.Enabled = false;
```

Presumably `MainMenu` is a *class* and not a *variable*.  You can't access a member directly on a class unless that member is `static`.  As the error states, you need to reference an *instance* of `MainMenu`, not the class itself.

---

In a traditional sense, the difference can be illustrated as follows...

Accessing a `static` member on a class directly:

```
SomeClass.SomeMember();
```

Accessing a non-`static` member on an *instance* of a class:

```
var someInstance = new SomeClass();
someInstance.SomeMember();
```

Semantically this is a very important distinction.  `static` isn't just a keyword to throw around until something works, it changes the fundamental meaning of what it's applied to.

As a semantic example, consider a class `Person`.  If you want to ask a `Person` for some information, such as `HairColor`, then you'd need an *instance*.  Because any given instance of a person can have their own hair color, independent of other instances.  So you'd never call `Person.HairColor`, you'd call `someInstanceOfPerson.HairColor`.

---

You do reference the non-static member elsewhere here:

```
timer1.Stop();
```

So, is `timer1` a member of the *currently executing* class?  If so, just be consistent with that:

```
timer1.Enabled = false;
```

Otherwise, if this code is running somewhere else (somewhere outside of the class which defines `timer1`, then you need an *instance* of that class.  Without knowing more about your code, the *absolute simplest* would be as above:

```
var mainMenu = new MainMenu();
mainMenu.timer1.Enabled = false;
```

*However*, I don't know anything about your `MainMenu` class or its `timer1` member.  It may be private, you may have another instance of that class already and not want to operate on a new one, etc.

The point, however, remains the same.  You need to identify *which* `MainMenu` (which instance of it) you want to reference.  You can't just reference the general class itself.

Answer (score -2):

Declare timer1 this way:
public static Timer timer1;

Comment: The "make every static" approach to solving problems generally creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @David - Agreed.  `static` has it's uses, but it can also be very, very dangerous and lead to lots of...."entertaining" bugs to track down and fix.

Comment: He didn't ask for best practices, he asked for a solution.  If we get into best practices then we could start with him trying declare a string variable with the name 123, which won't even compile.

Comment: @ClayVerValen: Throwing around keywords just to get one line of code to compile, at the expense of making the rest of the system fail, isn't really a solution.

Comment: Given that it won't compile, not sure what you might mean by "system."  Regardless, given the source code in the post and the question it is safe to say the poster is new to C# and likely OOP.  We can't all be software consultants (but we can both have Magenic on our resume - ;-). You can tell Paul I said "Hi".