# Unable to use AutoMapper.Mapper.Map method with ASP.NET Core 3.0 Web API

Tags: automapper

I am following Pluralsight to learn Web API concepts. I'm trying to map Book entity to the Book DTO object which is defined inside Models folder. But, I am getting below error.

I'm getting error like:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Mapper.Map(object)'

I could not get much help from google as well. When googled for the same, I found two similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505181/error-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-non-static-field-method-or-prop), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop). There, I felt sense but I am not understanding how to apply the same rule in my case.

Can anyone please help me to resolve the issue!

Comment: you have to create a mapper instance.

Comment: @DanielA.White: When I tried for that, I need to provide `IConfigurationProvider`. How can I get this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275195/how-to-set-up-automapper-in-asp-net-core

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu: Thank you man, looks like it is working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed Lucian Bargaoanu suggestion and arrived to below solution.

Write the below code in `ConfigureServices` method:

`services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));`

Introduced constructor dependency, and used `IMapper` functionality like below:

```
public class BookResultFilterAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    public BookResultFilterAttribute(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }
    public async override Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var resultFromAction = context.Result as ObjectResult;
        if(resultFromAction?.Value == null
            || resultFromAction.StatusCode < 200
            || resultFromAction.StatusCode >= 300)
        {
            await next();
            return;
        }
        resultFromAction.Value =  _mapper.Map<Models.Book>(resultFromAction.Value);
        await next();
    }
}
```